# MacBook Pro (Mavericks) sees details of non connected wifi network

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, wifi

I have a MacBook Pro, connected to my private Wi-Fi (Apple Time Capsule) network.  I have another Wi-Fi guest network (Devolo). Opening who's on my Wi-Fi shows details of machines connected to my guest network, opening Devolo cockpit allows me to see and configure the Devolo Wi-Fi network, even when I'm connected to the other private network?

Comment: Are you sure that these are two separate networks or just the same network with different a private SSID and a guest SSID?  Get an IP address from your "private" network and one from your "guest" network and post them to your question.

Comment: 1) Have you activated the Guest Account option in the Devolo setup via the Cockpit app? 2) Does the Devolo network share the same wireless router or router-modem as your Time Capsule for Internet access? 3) What is the exact network structure / how exactly are the network devices connected ?

Comment: It would help if you state the exact model name of the network devices (wireless router, Devolo adapters). Oh, and what is it that you actually want to do?

Comment: In response to Allan:  I have one livebox Orange to connect to internet, via ethernet one Timecapsule connected to the livebox, this TC generates one WIFI network, and via ethernet a Devolo 1200 connected to the livebox, this Devolo generates another WIFI elsewhere in the house.  If I connect to the livebox, I get IP 192.168.1.12, if I connect to the guest network I get IP 192.168.1.12

Comment: To @DictionaricsAnonymous : Guest account on Devolo is not activated. Network structure:  one Livebox Orange (WIFI disabled), to connect to internet.  On this, via ethernet one Timecapsule, that generates a WIFI network.  On the livebox as well via ethernet a Devolo 1200 to send the internet to a different part of the house, where a Devolo 1200 captures the signal from the electricity wires and generates another WIFI network different network name, different password.

Comment: To @DictionaricsAnonymous: I don't really want to do anything, I'm just confused that when I'm connected to my private wifi network, and I open Devolo cockpit, I can see the entire Devolo set up, access it and change it, without being connected to it.  Similarly, when I'm connected to my private network and run "whoisonmywifi", I get detailed info of who is on my guest network.  As I have many guests using my guest network, I'd like to understand and avoid a risk of guests having access to my private network.

Comment: Time Capsule seemed to be set up in bridge mode.  Switched it back to DHCP & NAT and solved the issue.  Thanks for the help !

Comment: @klanomath : kind of you to comment ironically on my typo / lay our errors.  You might want to check yours as well:  it's a MacBook Pro and not a MacBook Proo ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't the simple explanation be that the networks are routing traffic between them.

Check your router settings, it could be as simple as bridge mode on one of them. Also, map out the DHCP servers and network ranges on paper in case writing it down lets you realize there aren't actually two networks or if one is NAT translated as an address on the other.

Comment: Thanks @bmike, my Time Capsule was indeed in bridge mode.